# Is it possible to force Text widget to use two line space?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to find out a method to force Flutter `Text` widget to use two text lines space even if the line is only one.
For example in the below photo one card is lower than the other one due to the fact that `Text` widget use only one line space.

[image]

Does anyone know some trick to force `Text` widget to use `maxLines` space even if only one line is needed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding `minLines` to `Text` is currently an open feature request. You can track it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31134)

For now, a suggested workaround is to use:

```
str = 'example'; 

Text(
  str + '\n',
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

Comment: Pretty clean solutiion!  Thanks alot

Answer (score 10):

you can use **\n** to set minimum lines *(it is a trick)*

this issue is still open [Github: Add minLines to Text (flutter issue)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31134)

```
          Text(
            '${product.name}\n\n', //equal minlines: 3
            maxLines: 3,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style:
                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use *height* property in *TextStyle*:

```
Text(
  "Some lines of text",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14.0,
    height: 1.5 //set height as you want
  )
)
```

another option would be to use *Spacer()*:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Begin'),
    Spacer(), // Defaults to a flex of one.
    Text('Middle'),
    // Gives twice the space between Middle and End than Begin and Middle.
    Spacer(flex: 2),
    Text('End'),
  ],
)
```

you can find more details about Spacer in the [official docs here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I found.

You can set all text styles in one place and get it like so

```
static TextStyle subtitle2(Color color) =>
  initStyle(color, 14.0, FontWeight.w600);

static TextStyle initStyle(
 Color color, 
 double fontSize, 
 FontWeight fontWeight) =>
  TextStyle(
      height: 1.2,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      color: color,
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
      fontFamily: 'OpenSans');
```

Don't forget to set height property of Text Style

Then you can define your text like this

```
TextStyle textStyle = AppTextStyle.headline6(AppColors.onBackground);
int lines = 3;
...
Container(
      height: textStyle.height! * textStyle.fontSize! * lines,
      child: Text('Title', style: textStyle))
```

For me work Perfectly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw17U.jpg)

Comment: It works for me.

double titleHeight = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.height! * Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.fontSize! * 2;

SizedBox(
  height: titleHeight,
  child: Text(
    "${item['name']}",
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
Row(
     children: [
         Expanded(
           flex: 1,
           child: Text(
              'Your long text goes here, you can add as much as you want',
              maxLines: 2,   /// you can change it on your requirements, or may be ignore it
              ),
      )
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that doesn't require setting `maxLines` is to place the `Text` in a `Stack` with another `Text` with a (mostly) identical style (except transparent) that has exactly `n` lines.

That way, Flutter will paint both, and the size it takes will be whatever text is more lines. As an extra benefit, you can align the display Text too, making it centred it you want (for example)

```
return Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(
      "\n\n\n",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium.copyWith(
            color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      "Single Line of Text",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    ),
  ],
);
```

I'll do this quite often if I have a bit of UI where the text changes between one of several possible values, and I don't want the container it's wrapped in to change size every time. Works with buttons, chips, paragraphs, whatever. And also works with the user's font scaling and any translations of the text too.